# Check if internet connection is providing a dynamic or static IP in OSX

Tags: macos, ip, static-ip, dynamic-ip

Is there a way to check if my internet connection is with a dynamic or static IP? I'm running OSX.

Comment: Is your router set to DHCP?  Get it to renew it's lease a couple of times or power cycle a couple of times - if you get the same IP, and you've asked your ISP to provide you with a static one, chances are you're getting one.  I assume you gave your ISP the MAC address of your router?

Comment: Check your ISP's account settings / accounts page / products page. They should tell you straight out whether they provide Dynamic or Static IP addresses. What ISP are you with ?

Comment: Since question is how to check it within the operating system (without restarting a router), then I consider [this](http://serverfault.com/a/143119/145512) to be a good answer.

Comment: And [Finding out if an IP address is static or dynamic?](http://serverfault.com/q/143062/145512) and [Detect whether public IP address is dynamic or static](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11537401/1418463)